# Arduino crash and reboot at "random points"

Tags: c++, c, crash, arduino, reboot

I'm working on a very important school project, which is an MP3 player with a web interface and a webserver using an arduino mega.
when I want to use any function of the ethernet lib, I have to pause the music because the ethernet shield and the mp3 player shield are using the same spi bus. But when I change the volume, that causes a 1s freeze in the music. to avoid that I created new functions that pause the music, call a function of the ethernet lib and the resume.

```
bool clientAvailable(EthernetClient &client){
  MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
  bool a = client.connected();
  MP3player.resumeDataStream ();
  return a;
}
int clientConnected(EthernetClient &client){
  MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
  int a = client.available();
  MP3player.resumeDataStream ();
  return a;
}
void stopClient(EthernetClient &client){
  MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
  client.stop();
  MP3player.resumeDataStream ();
}

void checkForClient(int loading){
  String firstLine;
  MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  MP3player.resumeDataStream();
  if (client) {
    if(!loading){
      Serial.println(F("new client")); // CRASH HERE
      bool endLn(false);
      char chr;
      int i(0);
      while (clientConnected(client)) {
        char received[clientAvailable(client)+2];
        while (clientAvailable(client)) {
          MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
          char c = client.read();
          MP3player.resumeDataStream ();
           received[i] = c;
          Serial.print(c); // OR HERE
          if(!endLn){
            firstLine += c;
            if (c == '\n'){
            endLn = true;
            }
          }
          ++i;
        }
        received[i+1] = '\0';
        i = 0;
        if(endLn){
          Serial.println();
          endLn = false;
          Serial.print(F("first line : "));
          Serial.println(firstLine);
        }
```

what I get in output :

```
new û192.168.0.123
```

there is an IP at the end because this is where the arduino reboot and that's the first thing I display.
If I delete the "client.println(F("new client")) line, the error will occur on the client.print(c) line (after displaying 3 or 4 chars). if I remove this one too, it will crash somewhere but I don't know where.

I checked the memory, I have like 600 bytes left at this point of the program.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: How is your watchdog configured? Is it disabled? If not, where is the code that service the watchdog?

Comment: I don't know about the code, but just reading the question text fills me with a deep sense of unease and foreboding....   It feels like you are attending a patient with multiple trauma and are asking how to apply band-aid:(   I hope I'm wrong, but I think your design is bleeding out.

Comment: @Lundin it wasn't so I tried to disable it but nothing changed should I enable it and configure it instead ?

Comment: @MartinJames that's just because i'm trying to explain a code of about 430 lines in 6, and I'm not very skilled with english...
if you want more details, there is this 1s delay because I have to get the data from the client and extract the infos from it. before, I had somthing like:
pause - 
ethernet function - 
stuff causing a 1s delay - 
ethernet function - 
resume.
now I want something like
pause - 
ethernet func - 
resume - 
stuff causing a 1s delay - 
pause - 
ethernet func - 
resume - 
So I don't have this freeze everytime I change the volume.

Comment: Code crashing when you run a well-tested library function, which in turn performs as slow data transmission very much sounds like the watchdog.

Comment: but this line was not causing any problem before I started to use my custom functions

Comment: when I enable the watchdog timer, the working part of my code doesn't work anymore
edit : i'm stupid, I just forgot to reset it

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a low RAM condition.

Also, you shouldn't use the `String` class for `firstLine`.  It causes many problems, some of which can occur at random times.

Just use a character array like you did for `received`.  Store each character in the array until the newline character arrives, and increment the length for each character:

```
void checkForClient(int loading){
  char    firstLine[60];
  uint8_t firstLineLen = 0;

  MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  MP3player.resumeDataStream();
  if (client) {
    if(!loading){
      Serial.println(F("new client")); // CRASH HERE
      bool endLn(false);
      char chr;
      int i(0);
      while (clientConnected(client)) {
        char received[clientAvailable(client)+2];
        while (clientAvailable(client)) {
          MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
          char c = client.read();
          MP3player.resumeDataStream ();
          received[i] = c;
          Serial.print(c); // OR HERE
          if (!endLn) {
            if (firstLineLength < sizeof(firstLine)-2)
              firstLine[ firstLineLength++ ] = c;
            if (c == '\n') {
              endLn = true;
              firstLine[ firstLineLength ] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate
            }
          }
          ++i;
        }
        received[i+1] = '\0';
        i = 0;
        if(endLn){
          Serial.println();
          endLn = false;
          Serial.print(F("first line : "));
          Serial.println(firstLine);
        }
```

This will also save about 1600 bytes of program space.  There are many reasons to avoid String, and many people have written about the pitfalls.  If you use `String` elsewhere in your program, you should use a similar approach to eliminate it.

Another technique to reduce RAM is to avoid storing the data when it comes in, and then using it later.  Instead, use it immediately:

```
void checkForClient(int loading){

  MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  MP3player.resumeDataStream();
  if (client) {
    if(!loading){
      Serial.println(F("new client")); // CRASH HERE

      Serial.print(F("first line : "));
      bool endLn(false);

      char chr;
      int i(0);
      while (clientConnected(client)) {
        char received[clientAvailable(client)+2];
        while (clientAvailable(client)) {
          MP3player.pauseDataStream ();
          char c = client.read();
          MP3player.resumeDataStream ();
          received[i] = c;
          if (!endLn) {
            Serial.print(c); // printed now instead of saved for later
            if (c == '\n') {
              endLn = true;
            }
          }
          ++i;
        }
        received[i+1] = '\0';
        i = 0;
        if (endLn) {
          Serial.println();
          endLn = false;
          //Serial.println(firstLine); // NOT NEEDED, already printed!
        }
```

That saves all the RAM you would have used for `firstLine`.

You didn't post your entire program for our review, so you'll have to look for other variables that are too big, or that could be declared *inside* a routine (i.e., a local variable) instead of at file scope (i.e., a global variable, declared outside of any routines).

Comment: thanks for these advices, but unfortunatly, it didn't worked... there's still a little improvement tho, that's what I get :

`new client
GET / HTTP¯192.168.0.123`

it's only doing that since I added those functions but I don't see why.

here is the full code : http://pastebin.com/BWFqVGEv

Comment: I will also change the strings in my mp3 struct

Comment: @RedSkidy, I'm glad it's better.  BTW, you can edit your original question and include your sketch.  Most people won't download something to answer a question... except for libraries.  If you use a library, post a *link* to the one you are using, don't *include* it in your post.

Comment: I don't think the libraries are very important in this case. Even if there is a small improvement, it's still doing the same crash. As it got better using char arrays instead of strings I guess the problem comes from a lack of memory but it only does that since I added those functions, is there any reason they would consume memory ?

Comment: @RedSkidy, you don't think the libraries or the rest of your code are very important?  Sounds like you already know the answer.

Comment: it's more because i'm only using the basic functions of well tested libs made by people a lot more experienced than me and I already used these functions and they worked before, but you're probably right so these are the libraries used : SFEMP3Shield : https://mpflaga.github.io/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/class_s_f_e_m_p3_shield.html
Arduino Ethernet : https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/ethernet

also sdfatlib but it's not used in this part of the code : https://mosquino.googlecode.com/hg/libraries/sdfatlib-mosquino/html/index.html